# C# Converting YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY ("-" TO "/")

Tags: c#, datetime

Hey I have been having trouble with something.

```
string record = el.InnerText;
var result1 = parseString(record);
var StartDate = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{0}", r)).ToArray());
//DateTime strStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "mm-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var EndDate = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{1}", r)).ToArray());
//DateTime strEndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "mm-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is the `parseString` function:

```
private static List<string[]> parseString(string input)
    {
        var pattern = @"Start\s+Date:\s+([0-9-]+)\s+End\s+Date:\s+([0-9-]+)\s+(?:Warranty\s+Type:\s+\w+\s+)?Status:\s+(\w+)\s*";
        return Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().ToList().ConvertAll(m => new string[] { m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value });
    }
```

The `DateTimes` aren't working because I am **guessing** that "-" is not a valid character when converting a `string` to `DateTime`.

I tried `record = record.Replace("-", "/")` but that ended up messing up my string and it stopped showing up (from html page).

Comment: Could you give us a sample of `input` we could work on ?

Comment: If you were doing it that way you'd probably have to replace with "//" since I'm pretty sure forward slashes need to be escaped.

Comment: Your formats for `DateTime.ParseExact` are wrong, for starters. You want to use `MM`, not `mm`, at the very least.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a minimal (non)working example, perhaps in the form of a unit test or similar? Doing so should greatly help anyone trying to answer the question. Isolating the problem as much as possible is also often a good way to find what the error is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `-`. There is nothing wrong with that. But you seem to use small letter `m` instead of capital letter `M` to indicate your month:

```
//DateTime strStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "mm-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(Also, note that you put it in the comment - making it less visible!)

Change it to:

```
//Note the capital MM
DateTime strStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That's why you got the error. The small letter `m` is for minute, not month. To indicate month, use capital `M`

Comment: @JohnClifford thanks.. it was hidden in the comment. I did not spot it at first too..

Comment: sorry! it was commented out because I was testing my code and forgot about it

Comment: @Havoux that was the issue (most probably). Test it again and see if everything is OK. :)

Comment: @Ian you da real mvp - another quick question if you know it. I want to compare this date to a date that has /'s instead of -'s, Does it matter?

Comment: @Havoux comparing with /'s instead of -'s ? as in? do you have example?

Comment: @Ian I should probably post it as a different question honestly :P

Answer (score 1):

```
string res = "2016030";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(res, "yyyyddMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```